# Need to extend a regex to support '{}'

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
({(?!d})(?!{)(?<!{{)[^}]+})
```

it macthes any digit/string inside curly braces "{}", I need to extend it to also match no string/white spaces between 2 curly braces like the following

```
 {}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or you just need it and came here to get teh full codez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you just change the + (one or more) to a * (zero or more)?

`({(?!d})(?!{)(?<!{{)[^}]*})`

Comment: DUH :-) I was looking under the light it seems